# Add a driver module to embedded linux

Tags: compilation, embedded-linux, uart, buildroot

I have a task that consists in implementing a driver for an RF module.

The RF module communicate with the blackFin609 microcontroller using UART.

In a first step i created a uClinux image and download it in the BlackFin609 using uBoot and now i have to add the driver module to the kernel.

This is my first experience with embedded linux so i have no idea on how to add a driver module to linux.

Could you please point me to an easy tutorial, i find a lot of long tuto but i don't know from where to start, thanks in advance

Comment: In Linux, UART drivers are typically under the **tty** subsystem (i.e. **drivers/tty/serial/**).  Interfacing to a UART in Linux is best done through the userspace APIs, rather than trying to access the UART in kernelspace using a kernel module.  Otherwise you're pretty much on your own developing a new UART driver dedicated to interfacing with this RF module (e.g. it would not be a portable driver).

Comment: @sawdust, thank you for your answer, Ok, so you mean i have to implement a layer upper tty subsystem, could you please suggest me a nice step by step tutorial, i really get lost

Comment: I didn't write anything about *"a layer upper tty subsystem"*.  The first task is define the userspace API for this device.  What functionality/services do you expect from the device/kernel?.  Next you define what I/O you need to perform with this RF module through the UART.  Only then do you write code.

Comment: I have to implement functions as configure, send_stream, receive_stream

Comment: @sawdust, A user space API is it equivalent to package ?

Comment: No, a package is merely a collection of (related) files made available by a distribution.  An API is a programming interface, e.g. procedures/functions available for a specific application.  The tty API uses standard open, read and write syscalls with the [termios](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) routines.  A userspace API for the RF module would define a new layer of routines that use the tty API on its back-end, and define/expose a new set of functions as required by the application.  This collection of routines could be incorporated into its own library